# form validation codeigniter greater than 0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code: 
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('pay', '', 'required', array("required" => "this field is required"));`

I neet to change to validate greater than 0.

Like this:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('pay', '', 'greater_than', array("greater_than" => "only values greater than 0"));`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need to add that rule like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pay', '', 'required| greater_than[0]');
```